# Addition of sparse array objects

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, linear-algebra, version-9, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

I have been having some trouble with the addition of large (but very sparse) matrices using SparseArray.

Here is the simplest example to illustrate the issue. First, I will define diagonal matrices with random boolean entries:

```
Do[A[i] = DiagonalMatrix@SparseArray@RandomChoice[{0, 1}, 10^4];, {i,1, 5}]
```

Now I add them:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Sum[A[i], {i, 1, 5}];]
```

In my system (Mathematica 9 in Mac OS) this operation takes 2.39 seconds. 
Next I implement this sequentially, adding one matrix to another at each step:

```
B = 0;
AbsoluteTiming[Do[B += A[i], {i, 5}];]
```

This operation takes in my machine 0.001226 seconds (!).
This seems to be independent of the method used to sum; all the following choices take approximately the same time:

```
Sum[A[i], {i, 1, 5}]
Total@Table[A[i], {i, 1, 5}]
Plus @@ Table[A[i], {i, 1, 5}]
A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5]
```

Of course, what I am really interested are non-diagonal matrices with non-trivial entries. Even though I could continue to use the aforementioned "sequential" approach, this behaviour is puzzling for me and I would really like to understand it.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Gabriel

Comment: On my machine, they all take about the same time. I would've expected `Sum` to be slow (especially with longer lists), but `Total` and direct addition should be fast.

Comment: Oh wait... I think I might know why. There was a bug in version 9, related to sparse arrays becoming normal. See here: [How to work around Mathematica hanging when showing a large SparseArray?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17960) Which version of _Mathematica_ 9 are you using?

Comment: @rm-rf My version is 9.0.1.0. And I have disabled the suggestive interface (in the Preferences menu) and it did not change anything.

Comment: This was reported (as you can see from the link), so I am very confident that the next version won't have this bug :-)  Until then the simplest workaround is to use floating point matrices instead of integer ones.